# How to make a String replacement program without any for loop in java?

Tags: java

**For Example :-**

```
String str = "Hello How are u!"
```

Replacement character with each other.

```
a one
e two
i three
o four
u five
```

**OutPut**

```
Htwollfour Hfourw onertwo five!
```

How do I do that without any looping ?

Comment: str.replaceAll("a", "one;"); like that for a , e, i ,o ,u

Comment: Why would you need a for loop in the first place?

Comment: what are your constrains exactly? does no looping means not using standard methods which loops through the string as well? does it exclude using recursion?

Comment: @ScaryWombat i'm not saying it's needed, i just want to know constrains

Comment: @user902383 Yep understood.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to use a stream. And a map:

```
Map<Character, String> mapping = new HashMap<>();
mapping.put('a', "one");
mapping.put('e', "two");
mapping.put('i', "three");
mapping.put('o', "four");
mapping.put('u', "five");

String res = "Hello How are u!".chars()
        .mapToObj(ch -> mapping.getOrDefault((char) ch, 
                                  Character.toString((char) ch)))
        .collect(Collectors.joining());

System.out.println(res);
```

And that prints `Htwollfour Hfourw onertwo five!`